# Getting multiple relationship property returns from a single cypher call

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to cypher, neo4j and graph databases in general.  The data model I was given to work with is a tad confusing, but it looks like the nodes are just GUID placeholders with all the real "data" as properties on relationships to the nodes (which relates each node back to node zero).

Each node (which basically only has a guid) has a dozen relations with key/value pairs that are the actual data I need.  (I'm guessing this was done for versioning?.. )

I need to be able to make a single cypher call to get properties off two (or more) relationships connected to the same node -- here is two calls that I'd like to make into one call;

```
start n = Node(*)
match n-[ar]->m
where has(ar.value) and has(ar.proptype) and ar.proptype = 'ccid' 
return ar.value
```

and

```
start n = Node(*)
match n-[br]->m
where has(br.value) and has(br.proptype) and br.proptype = 'description'
return br.value
```

How do I go about doing this in a single cypher call?

EDIT - for clarification;

I want to get the results as a list of rows with a column for each value requested.

Something returned like;

n.id as Node, ar.value as CCID, br.value as Description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe you can just do this:

```
start n = Node(*)
match n-[r]->m
where has(r.value) and has(r.proptype) and (r.proptype = 'ccid' or r.proptype = 'description') 
return r.value
```

See [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-operators.html) for more documentation on Cypher operations.

Based on your edits I'm guessing that you're actually looking to find cases where a node has both a ccid and a description? The question is vague, but I think this is what you're looking for.

```
start n = Node(*)
match n-[ar]->m, n-[br]->m
where (has(ar.value) and has(ar.proptype) and ar.proptype = 'ccid') and 
      (has(br.value) and has(br.prototype) and br.proptype = 'description') 
return n.id as Node, ar.value as CCID, br.value as Description
```

Comment: You should qualify the OR by surrounding it with parentheses, as this evaluation should be mistaken.

Comment: That does work yes, but I'd like to get it so that I can get them in the same row of results.  Meaning, i want to say return n.id, r.ccid, r.description or whatever..

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not totally understanding. Could you possibly update your question with more detail since it seems to not accurately reflect exactly what you want?

Comment: Edited.  Added AR and BR for the a and b relation then added a psuedo return value on bottom showing i want both the a and b relation on a single line

Comment: @JasonEllis I'm not certain I got your meaning, but I think that edit should get you what you want.

Comment: Slater, your edit seems reasonable and seems like the right solution, but the match line is causing neo to hang.
Should "match n-[ar]-m, n-[br]-m" take a long time?

Comment: Okay so this is exactly what I want.. thank you.. but apparently doing node(*) against my dataset of 5k nodes, 60k relations and 500k properties is causing some timeout issues.. Time to start working with limits I think =)  Thanks

Comment: @JasonEllis heh, yea, I was going to mention that Node(*) is probably not best practices, but I figured you'd figure it out on your own. Happy Hacking.

Answer (score 0):

You can match relationships from two sides:

```
start n = Node(*)
match m<-[br]-n-[ar]->m
where has(ar.value) and has(ar.proptype) and ar.proptype = 'ccid' and 
has(br.value) and has(br.proptype) and br.proptype = 'description'
return ar.value, br.value
```